# rails polymorphic setup error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I think I'm supposed to use polymorphic for this, but when I tried the code I could find to solve it, it didn't work.

In plain English, I am creating a Message, and I want it to 
1) either belong_to a Guide or a Member
2) has_one Trip or Bid

I get a rollback error when I try and save a new Message and when I try and reference the "first_name" of a Guide in a View via a message I get the following error:

```
undefined method `guide' for #<Message:0x0000000487bd48>
Did you mean?  guide_id
```

These are my models:

```
class Guide < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, as: :messageable
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, as: :messageable
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :messageable, polymorphic: true
  has_one :bid or :trip
end
```

This is the code snippet for showing the first_name, for what it's worth the text of the message msg.message displays just fine.

```
<% if @bid.messages.present? %>
  <% @bid.messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p>From: 
    <% if msg.guide_id.present? %>
      <%= msg.guide.first_name %>
    <% elsif msg.member.present? %>
      <%= msg.member.first_name %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <p>Message: <%= msg.message %></p>
<% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>No messages</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Instead of `has_one :bid or :trip` (which does not work like you thought), why not do `belongs_to :biddable, polyphorphic: true`? You can use a better name than `biddable` to represent both `bid` and `trip`.

Answer (score 0):

You always keep referencing the polymorphic name, so instead of doing `msg.guide.first_name`, you use: `msg.messageable.first_name`

It might be worth to share your database migration as well. In the code you are checking for: `guest_id`, which shouldn't be part of the Message model. There should only be an attribute called `messagable_id`, so the view can be simplified:

```
<% if @bid.messages.present? %>
  <% @bid.messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p>From: <%= msg.messageable.first_name %></p> 
  <p>Message: <%= msg.message %></p>
<% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>No messages</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, so now I'm running into an issue when I try to create a message. No matter what I've tried with the controller it doesn't seem like I can get a message to be created. How do I reference the guide or member who is creating the message in the controller? I use Devise for each so in theory guides and members can have overlapping user names.

In doing more research before this comment I did see the .build_polymorhism method but in testing in the console it didn't give me a ".build_guide()" method/option like I would expect

Comment: You always create the relation from either Member or Guide. So something like: `Guide.build_message(message:'test message').save` This automatically sets the Guide ID

Comment: Hmmm, so I get a "NoMethodError: undefined method `build_message'" when I try that. As an aside, since there is also a "trip_id" and/or a "bid_id" associated with the message model, do I also need to reference that in the call to build the model? Guide.build_message(message:'test message', trip_id:'1')? Since a message is "owned" by either a Guide or a Member, but "attached" to either a Bid or a Trip, do I need to also make Bid/Trip polymorphic? Would that then change how the Message is built?

Comment: Sorry, you need to use build_message from a single guide. So you do: `Guide.find(3).build_message(message:'test message').save`, as an example, you'd want to dynamically find the correct guide of course.